# Does anyone have instructions for setting up Graylog?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, graylog

I am trying to review the Graylog software to monitor my various server.  Basically looks like a syslog analyser.  My problem is their instructions/manual may be complete and exhaustive, but it is written like a reference manual.  I.e., if you know what you are looking for it's great, but if you are just getting started, it is pretty much useless.

Has anyone ever set up a Graylog server and got it running?

Comment: According to https://community.graylog.org/t/graylog-wont-start-after-new-installation/1844/18 you've had Graylog working. What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Thats nice tutorial to how to setup graylog on ubuntu 16.04
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logs-with-graylog-2-on-ubuntu-16-04

Using collector-sidecar you can send logs to graylog by following this tutorial
http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.3/pages/collector_sidecar.html

Actually http://docs.graylog.org is the answer for all of them